# Spring (Security) dependency injection

Tags: spring, spring-security, dependency-injection, autowired

I asked a question more specific to my case about 2 hours ago, but I realised I'm not really addressing my problem at the root cause.

I have a Spring application that uses Spring Security. Throughout my application, (Controllers, service classes etc) I'm using dependency injection and it all works fine. However, I recently started configuring Spring Security, and I can't inject any dependencies inside the classes in my "security" package. Online I read somewhere: "Also when you use `@Autowired` in the class of which you created a new instance, the Spring context will not be known to it and thus most likely this will also fail" and I was wondering if this maybe had something to do with my issue. My spring configuration basically has one "starting-point", that is the following class:

```
@Component
@Service
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.register(SecSecurityConfig.class);

        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        sc.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }
}
```

This code is run on startup. As you can see, it is registering the `SecSecurityConfig.class` which is where I configure Spring Security. Inside of that class and onwards (all classes it uses and all classes that those classes use) I can't inject any dependencies. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what the problem could be. Sorry if I'm unclear or incorrect - please tell me so, I find the concept of DI somewhat hard to grasp. My component-scan in XML is: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.qars"/>` which is the package that my security package is also in.

Also all my classes are annotated with `@Component` or `@Service`

Comment: You are mixing XML and java config, possible but error prone. You are using Spring Security if you want that use the proper base classes for it (there is a special one that pre-rgisteres the filter etc. The `@Component` and `@Service` for this class are useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - which classes would that be? Do you have any reference you would recommend? - thanks

Comment: The Spring Security Reference guide is a good starting point.